# Why didn't they hide Hogwarts before the final battle using Fidelius Charm?

Tags: harry-potter

Before the final battle of Hogwarts, all professors of Hogwarts created some kind of shield around Hogwarts because Harry needed time and attack of Death Eaters needed to be delayed.

Instead of small delay, why didn't they simply avoided the war by vanishing Hogwarts using Fidelius Charm? As long as secret keeper was loyal, Hogwarts would stay hidden. This could have saved many innocent lives.

Where's the catch?

Comment: Well it didn't really work last time...

Comment: That's because secret keeper wasn't loyal last time.

Comment: What would have happened if the secret keeper were killed?  Would Hogwarts have been lost forever?  That wouldn't be so good.  (And what would happen to the people inside?)

Comment: @NateEldredge, I'd assume the secret-keeper would "tell" everyone in Hogwarts somehow the location of Hogwarts. If not, they may not have been able to be "inside Hogwarts". We don't know exactly how the charm works, but you could ask the same questions of if Peter had died (btw, did he "die" before or after Voldy "died"?).

Comment: @trysis: Pettigrew dies before Voldemort. A moment of hesitation at Malfoy Manor when he’s strangling Harry causes his silver hand to turn on him and kill him.

Comment: @alexwlchan, OK, I wasn't sure, thanks. My point was if Peter had died but didn't "tell" anyone (besides the Potters), we could be asking the same questions. He likely told *somebody*, though, so the point is moot.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That might work if you had a long preparation time, but it isn’t practical as a battle preparation technique, nor as a security measure. When Flitwick first introduces the Fidelius Charm, he explains that you can only learn about the secret from a single person:

> “An immensely complex spell,” he said squeakily, “involving the magical concealment of a secret inside a single, living soul. The information is hidden inside the chosen person, or Secret-Keeper, and is henceforth impossible to find – **unless, of course, the Secret-Keeper chooses to divulge it.**”
>
> — *Prisoner of Azkaban*, chapter 10, *The Marauder's Map*

It’s only useful if everybody already inside Hogwarts (including hundreds of students) are within the hidden castle. That makes the Secret-Keeper a bottleneck for your defensive strategy, who are otherwise stuck outside the castle until you can let them in. If the Death Eaters are approaching imminently, suddenly displacing the castle’s population beyond the boundary is a bad idea.

I’m also not convinced this would work. The location of Hogwarts is fairly well-known (in proximity to Hogsmeade) and many Death Eaters have been there before. It’s not an existing secret. Can you use the Fidelius Charm to make them forget the location of the school? As far as I know, the Charm has never been shown to be that powerful in the canon.

Comment: Indeed, the Fidelius charm seems to only make it impossible for someone to find out a secret they didn't know before, and cannot make someone forget what they already know. Otherwise everyone would have been able to make every embarrassing information about them to be forgotten.

Comment: But non pf Voldemort's supporters seemed to be able to enter the House of Black after the Fidelius Charm, and I am sure some of them would at least know where it was, even though they may not know any Blacks personally

Comment: When Dumbledore died all the people he told the location of the Black residence to became the secret-keepers. This implies there could be more than 1 secret-keeper. There are many other reasons this wouldn't work for Hogwarts, just pointing out that that reason isn't one of them.

Comment: @trysis: But Harry had to read a piece of paper *written by Dumbledore* to learn the location of Grimmauld Place in *Order of the Phoenix*, despite his Guard being in on the secret. As presented in canon, there are only multiple Secret-Keepers when the first dies. That would be unacceptable to the defenders of Hogwarts.

Comment: @alexwlchan, I was saying the fact that there can be more than one secret-keeper at a time after the first dies indicates that there can be more than one secret-keeper without anyone dying. Also, Harry's guard could not tell him the secret himself because Dumbledore was the secret-keeper, not him, so I don't know what the purpose of that statement was.

Comment: @trysis: If the Order didn’t have Secret-Keepers, was it because they chose not to, or because the original S-K was still alive? I think it’s not obvious. And I maintain that even with many Secret-Keepers, you still have a potentially dangerous bottleneck for getting people to safety.

Comment: Maybe the Order was short-handed, considering so many of its members kept dying, and each member had a "mission". Perhaps all the members couldn't help with each other's missions because there were too few of them to spare. It's not obvious, but there may be (somewhat) vallid reasons.

Comment: @alexwlchan, I said there were many other problems with the OP's plan, just that this may not be one of them. You may be right, or I may be right; we may never know.